# Flux getting stuck in case of any java.lang.Error(OOM)

Tags: java, project-reactor

In flux whenever there is OOM the whole process is getting stuck until we kill it manually. I have created an example to simulate it. Please refer the following code:

```
@Test
public void test_Flux() {
    Flux.range(1, 30)
            .parallel(6)
            .runOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6)))
            .doOnNext(this::writeValues)
            .sequential()
            .blockLast();
}

private void writeValues(int val) {
    if (val == 10) {
        throw new OutOfMemoryError("failed here");
        // throw new RuntimeException("failed here");
    }
    System.out.println("the thread name is :" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " val is :" + val);
    sleep(3);
}

private void sleep(int i) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(i * 1000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Can we crash here instead of getting stuck?

Comment: Wouldn't make sense to fix the cause of `OutOfMemoryError` instead of trying to catch it and handle?

Comment: Yes it would. But this issue in flux makes debugging so much difficult. Because the process was not failing in the event of OOM instead it was getting stuck for 12 hours and our monitor was killing it thinking it as zombie. So we had to go to great length to debug this, which should have been so much easier.